# Xcode, CMake unable to link C++ library with ObjC++ library

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, cmake

I have created a minimalistic C++ library that I want to use in my Xcode project. It has this directory structure -

```
library/
 
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - build/    // build files will reside here 
    - iOS.cmake // toolchain file
    - core/
        - CMakeLists.txt
        - squareroot.h
        - squareroot.cpp
    - platform/
        - CMakeLists.txt
        - squrerootwrapper.h
        - squarerootwrapper.mm
```

Project link - https://github.com/devojoyti/CMakeLibrary

Inside `build/` I am doing -

- `cmake ../ -G Xcode -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../iOS.cmake -D IOS_PLATFORM=SIMULATOR`
- `xcodebuild -target install -configuration Debug`

Basically what is happening, is I am building two libraries, one inside `core/` which calculates the squareroot of a number, another in `platform/` which is a ObjC wrapper on the C++ squareroot computation library. I am linking the core/ library inside platform/ library.

**Problem:**

Problem is, I am unable to link the library generated inside `core/`, with that of generated inside `platform/`. The code builds just fine, and the library (and the corresponding .h header file) is generated.

However, if I try to use it in my Xcode, it says this:

[image]

Clearly, the `core/` library functions are not accessible inside `platform/`.

I have tried fiddling with `C` and `CXX` flags, trying to add library using `find_library` first, and using different toolchain, for example, [this](https://github.com/leetal/ios-cmake) one here as well.

Platform specifications:

- MacOS Big Sur, 11.6.5, 2.3 Ghz i9
- CMake - 3.22.2
- Xcode - 13.2.1

Comment: Is the platform macOS or iOS?

Comment: Platform (for which the library is being built, is iOS Simulator, where it will be consumed by an iOS app), it is being built on macOS

Comment: This problem isn't macOS-, Xcode- or CMake-specific.  It's just the nature of how static libraries work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I finally got what was the problem.

- The libraries I was generating, were **static** libraries.
- Static libraries cannot resolve their dependencies on their own (i.e., here, library in `platform/` cannot resolve its dependency of `core/`) unless I explicitly add both of them to Xcode.
- It started working after I added both libraries (`core/` library and `platform/`) in Xcode.

**Explanation:**

- **Static Library**: Though you specify a dependency, it's not resolved by the toolchain. You'd have to specify all dependencies to the final executable.

  - e.g: `libB` depends on `libA` then when linking hello.exe which only calls methods of `libB` you've to specify both `libB.a` AND `libA.a` too for it to work
- **Dynamic/Shared Library**: Dependencies b/w libraries are resolved; just specifying the dependency needed by the final executable is good enough

  - You'd still have to make sure both .dylibs are in the same directory for `libB.dylib` to load `libA.dylib`

So, either create a dynamic library or add all the dependencies of the static library in Xcode as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assume libcore_lib.a is under core/

```
find_package(CORE core_lib HINTS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/core)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/core)
add_library(pim_ios ${PLATFORM_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(pim_ios ${CORE})
target_link_libraries(pim_ios PUBLIC "-framework Cocoa" "-framework AppKit" "-framework CoreData" "-framework Foundation")
```

Comment: It says - 

`CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CORE
    linked by target "pim_ios" in directory /Users/****/Work/library/platform
`

Basically, it is not able to find the core_lib :(

Comment: I've update it. By the way, You should make sure if libcore_lib.a is under directory ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/core

Comment: Again the same error. Is it working fine on your machine (assuming you have tried it ?) 
Also ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/core is the correct directory, checked with `message` command

Comment: sorry, I've no ios env now. But In my option, this type of error  is caused by (i)path (ii) lib (iii) header include.  I update it again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the Core/CMakeLists.txt, you can add:

```
target_include_directories(core_lib PUBLIC
$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>)
```

In another target which link with core_lib, it will include the directory "Core".